# HTML client side form validation, doesn't appear to be working in React app using JSON

Tags: json, reactjs

I'm coding a simple form with JSON, which doesn't appear to validate correctly.

Here's the component instance:

```
  class App extends Component {

  state = {
    data: [
      {id: 1, name:"a", age:29, qualification:"B.Com", rating:3},
      {id: 2, name:"b", age:35, qualification:"B.Sc", rating:5},
      {id: 3, name:"c", age:42, qualification:"B.E", rating:3},
    ],
    current: {}
  }

  onSubmit = (model) => {
    model.id = +new Date();
    alert(JSON.stringify(model));
    this.setState({
      data: [model, ...this.state.data]
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <DynamicForm className="form"
          title="Registration"
          model={[
            {key: "name", label: "Name", props: {required: true}},
            {key: "age",label: "Age", type: "number"},
            {key: "rating",label: "Rating", type: "number", props:{min:0,max:5}},
            {key: "qualification",label: "Qualification"},
          ]}
          onSubmit = {(model) => {this.onSubmit(model)}} 
        />

        <pre styles={{width:"300px"}}>
          {JSON.stringify(this.state.data)}
        </pre>

      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

So if you leave out the name input you don't get notified!

Does anyone out there know why?

Adding {required: true} to ...

{key: "name", label: "Name", props: {required: true}},

Has no affect!

Comment: It is unclear what `DynamicForm` is, and the validation is probably handled inside this component/library.

Comment: I've added the DynamicForm code above...

Comment: where are you validating the data?

Comment: I've added some more code above the render() method in app.js above...